# why are russian letters shown incorrectly?

Tags: russian

I have no idea why russian letters are shown incorrectly. For example in rhythmbox:
[image: in Rhythmmbox]

what's wrong?

Comment: Russian letters are not shown incorrectly. In fact, in the picture there are no Russian letters at all. What is shown incorrectly is the text: it seems that Rhytmbox believes that the text to be shown is in an encoding which does not correspond to the encoding used by whoever wrote the text. Does the text come from ID3 tags? What encoding do ID3 tags use? Is Rhytmbox aware of that encoding? As far as I can tell, the text is Windows-1251 encoding, while Rhytmbox believes it to be Windows-1252. You may want to convert ID3v1 tags to ID3v2 (which are encoded in UTF-8).

Comment: Unfortunately they are. If I play these songs on windows, they are shown as in russian letters which I downloaded.

Comment: Even some text files which are in russian letters have been  showed like that